# How to reformat a date values of a MySQL column?

Tags: mysql

I want to copy data of table into another but I have a pain for a column.

- **Table A** has a column *DP* of **type `VARCHAR(10)`** holding date values in String format this way '**dd/MM/yyyy**'.
- **Table B** has a column *DC* of **type `DATE`** holding date values in Date format this way: 'yyyy-MM-dd'.

If I alter the column DP to type DATE, then all its values will be converted to "0000-00-00".
And if I try to copy directly, an error will raise preventing from copying because DP values will not be recognized as DATE values in column DC.

So either, find a way to reformat DP values to DATE values respecting the pattern 'yyyy-MM-dd' and then copy or find some function to convert the french date to english date while copying.

Does anyone have a clue?
Regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function can handle this for you.

```
STR_TO_DATE(`DP`, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Answer (score 3):

You need 3 queries to do that:

1. ALTER a table to add a new column of DATE datatype
2. Use UPDATE query with [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to move your dates into new column in proper format
3. ALTER the table to drop the old column and rename new column to what it's supposed to be

Comment: that is it. the function did the trick. Much Thanks! Hope you don't mind that I accepted @Brad answer, as it came with the exact pattern to use.