# MySQL updating strings in a column to be DateTime

Tags: java, mysql

I am saving a date formatted with Javas `SimpleDateFormat` with the format "E. MMM-dd-YYYY hh:mm a zzz" eg "Sat. Apr-15-2017 10:44 PM EST" to a table as a VARCHAR.

How would I go about changing all of the pre-existing data to be in DateTime format?

Comment: Please provide examples of the format in the question.

Comment: My apologies, a date would be stored as Sat. Apr-15-2017 10:42 PM EST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
UPDATE `table`
SET `column` = STR_TO_DATE(`column`,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

refer to [change mysql comumn from varchar to datetime and convert data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875348/how-can-i-change-a-mysql-column-from-varchar-to-date-time-and-convert-the-data-a) post